# Difference between the closely related prepositions for "excluding"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, formality

The following cited words suggest the same meaning, as "excluding" could:

> - [Apart from](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/apart-from) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Barring](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barring) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Besides](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/besides) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Except](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/except) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Except for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/except%20for) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Excepting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excepting) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Excluding](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/excluding) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Other than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/other-than) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Save](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/save) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Save for](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/save) the last paragraph, the book is finished.
> - [Saving](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saving) the last paragraph, the book is finished.

Nothing seems different in the meaning of the sentences mentioned above, **but I don't know their subtle difference, informality and formality**. I just know that excluding and excepting are the formal prepositions, but I don't know about the rest of the prepositions stated above.

Comment: "Not counting his daughters" would be even funnier.

Comment: I mean, it's a very strange sentence ... why did you select it?

Comment: @AzorAhai, see the edited form, I hope it's fine now.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal, don't the dictionaries provide the formality and informality of the prepositions you mentioned here?

Comment: The grammar of when to use *except for* and when to use *except* is truly complex. Expecting somebody to explain it as part of a broad question like this is really asking too much.

Comment: Sometimes different words reflect same meaning in a given context.

Comment: @JasonBassford: "Saving *for* the last paragraph, the book is finished." would be completely incorrect. "Saving ..." or "Save for ...", but never "Saving for ...".

Comment: Reminder to everyone: answer in
answers, not in comments.
Comments are for asking
clarifying questions or
suggesting improvements to the
question, not for answering it;
they don't have the quality
assurance mechanisms that
answers do.

Comment: @JamesWolpert au contraire, the comments helped the OP in compiling grammatical and coherent sentences, without them, we would be reading "He has 5 children barring his daughters". Proofreading is off-topic, but the first draft has been proofread.

Comment: The question is far far too broad. Who has the time to go through NINE examples in detail and explain the subtle nuances and connotations of each one. I don't know why it wasn't closed.

Comment: @JasonBassford Follow the links: you're mistaken. 'Save' and 'saving' are perfectly grammatical on their own, just like 'except'. The 'for' is usually added for clarity, but they can all stand on their own.

Comment: @lly I don't know when, but Jason Bassford has left the house. There seems little point in nominating him when the comment no longer exists.

Comment: Iqbal Ahmed Siyal, please first recognise that the distinctions you ask about are beyond the comprehension of most native, let alone foreign speakers.

I suggest that the simple fact of recognising those differences and similarities makes you far more cognisant of anything relevant than almost any of u who might deign to answer.

Comment: "Barring" makes it sound like the paragraph has no LEGAL RIGHT to be in the book, so it is awkward to use it for an inanimate object that is not a person.

"Excepting" fools the reader into expecting that the rest of the phrase will describe that the last paragraph has privileges the other paragraphs don't.

"Saving" fools the reader into expecting that the rest of the phrase will describe that the last paragraph is going to be preserved or stored.  (It might just get thrown away or left as-is).

"Except" & "Save" are redundant contractions of "Except for" or "Save for"

Comment: Since there is as yet no final paragraph, indefinite article should be used.

Comment: @AceFrahm, I have recently seen an example sentence from OED that says: ‘The sowing of almost all crops, **barring** pulses, has been adversely affected.’ Now, Ace, please tell me that does this sentence suggest anything pertaining to the legal right of sowing crops of pulses?

Comment: @Eddy That's the problem with your example: plants don't have legal rights, people do.  By using the word "barring" when the phrase "except for" should have been used ( because the object is not a thinking human with rights ) the sentence becomes needlessly harder to understand.  Although the meaning could be understood anyway, it is the worst possible choice among the options listed.  Nearly no modern American person would choose "barring" in speech or writing for this use.  Perhaps some British (or former colonials) might, but that would instantly mark them as "foreigner" to Americans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the basic idea. They are all synonyms for "not counting ~".

The minor differences in connotation (to the extent anyone notices) mostly derive from etymology and frequency: what's the original language of the word? what's the base meaning of the verb or noun they come from? and how often do people use it in this sense?

In general, **the latinate and uncommon words sound more formal**, so “except” sounds less folksy than “besides” (they’re both common but one is latinate) and “save” feels more formal, since **(a)** [it’s so uncommon in this sense](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=save_ADP%2Cexcept_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) that even native speakers (like Mr Bassford above) forget it can be used this way and **(b)** because this use [follows its medieval appearance as an ablative absolute in Latin](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171457).

- “Except” is [the most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besides_ADP%2Cexcept_ADP%2Capart+from_ADP%2Cexcept+for_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), [followed by](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besides_ADP%2Cexcept_ADP%2Capart+from_ADP%2Cexcept+for_ADP%2Cother+than_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) “other than;”
- “apart from” and “besides” are a little folskier than “except for” and [used about as often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besides_ADP%2Cexcept_ADP%2Capart+from_ADP%2Cexcept+for_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3); in this particular case, “besides” [is now more often used in *negative* constructions](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/18071) (“Besides the first 235 pages, I haven’t gotten any work done on the book”);
- in this case, you probably wouldn’t go with “except” since its sense flows better *following* the general status (“the book is done except [for] the last paragraph”); the other three are all better for what’s going on here, which is foregrounding the exception rather than the general status;
- “excluding,” “excepting,” and “barring” are both [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=besides_ADP%2Capart+from_ADP%2Cexcept+for_ADP%2Cexcepting%2Cexcluding%2Cbarring&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) and—because of the suffix—more active, implying (esp. with the forceful “barring”) that an active measure is being taken to exclude something; “barring” is usually more specific than these other synonyms: people use it to mean they’re *specifically excluding* some possibility from consideration;
- the variants of “save” [are less common still](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excepting%2Cexcluding%2Cbarring%2Csave_ADP%2Csaving_ADP%2Csave+for_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), feel more formal, and have the connotation that something is specifically being set aside for mention, consideration, use, &c. at a later time; they also have a related and still more formal (but mostly outdated) sense of “without prejudice to” or “with due regard for” that you see when talking about people’s dignity, honour, &c. The OED also thinks using “saving” in this sense [is mildly Scottish](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171469).

In this specific case,

- *Apart from* and *other than* both sound fine.
- *Except* is a little awkward because it much more often *follows* the general status. You could rephrase to “the book is finished except the last paragraph,” which highlights the nearly complete state of the work. *Except for* works a little better leading the sentence, but suffers similarly, if less acutely.
- *Save* and *saving* are a little awkward because they’re so [seldomly](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175022) used this way; people’s first thought will be that you’re giving them an order *to* save the last paragraph for some unknown purpose. It works a little better if you use *for* or *only*, but it’s still archaic enough to come off as being pretentious.
- *Besides* is a little awkward being used with a positive statement, which usually switches it over to its related sense of “also,” “in addition to.” You *can* use this way, but it’s a bit jarring.
- *Barring* doesn’t work at all. You’re not going to take specific action to exclude the last paragraph. You could rephrase to, “barring an act of God, I’ll have the book to you by Wednesday. I just need to decide on a final paragraph.” *Excluding* and *excepting* suffer similarly, if less forcefully. It’d be more natural to express those ideas conditionally: “If you exclude the last paragraph, the book’s already finished.”

Answer (score 0):

This is a super loaded question and I'm not interested in going down the list and offering comments about each word. But I will talk about a few them that are definitively weird/ridiculous.

1."Excepting for __" is rarely used ever. 2. "Barring" just sounds intense to me and I would not use it in formal writing.

Lastly, you forgot "besides."

Comment: To the person who deleted their comment to me about how "excepting for" is not on the list: it was. OP modified the question after my post.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/458376/1 This is the original question, which was posted Aug 1 at 18:05 This is the second version https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/458376/2 posted Aug 1 at 18:24.

Comment: This is the current version, edited by a different user, posted  Aug 4 at 8:06: https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/458376/5 At no time did the OP write "excepting for"

Comment: Mari-Lou, sorry about that. I really thought that I read it.